# White Magic consumes Vital Energy, what could be the limitation for Dark Magic?

Tags: magic, super-powers

In my story, there are two kind of magic powers: White Magic and Dark Magic. 
White magic are powers such as Telekinesis and its limitation is the consumption of vital energy: The more the user does white magic, the more vital energy he loses, and in the end he could die.

Dark Magic is more offensive, such as Throw Energy Balls or Throw lightnings. My idea is to have a different kind of limitation instead of Vital Energy consumption, but I am not sure what kind of limitation could be. Can anyone think on some kind of possible limit about this?

EDIT:

With Vital Energy I mean what in some oriental religions mean as Ki, so a human has some vital energy and when it is consumed, the human stops living.

EDIT 2: I would like to share some idea I have recently thought, so you can help me to find any flaw. One idea is to, instead of user Ki, Dark Magic consumes Ki from the surrounding living beings, such as animals, humans, plants and even planets and stars. The problem is that with this idea, the user can use the power he wants without being worried.

Comment: "vital energy"?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, programmer. In order for us to provide a reasonable answer and for this question not to be closed as either unclear or primarily opinion based, could you please add clarification on what you mean by 'vital' energy? I assume you mean some form of life force, but ultimately energy is energy. If you're suggesting that white magic reduces lifespan, why would not dark magic do the same, only more so because it releases more emergy?

Comment: This is easy. if *white* magic consumes *vital* energy, then it's clear that *black* magic consumes *lethal* energy.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I have edited the text explaining what Vital Energy means.

AlexP => By lethal energy, you mean that the more the user uses Dark Magic, the powers are less likely to kill?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to worldbuilding. Please remember that this is a magic system you have defined. You can have White and Dark magic both be powered off of Vital Energy if you want, or if a human has multiple energies it can use the alternatives to setup a ying and yang setup. At the end of the day, you decide how magic in your world works, and we can tell you the flaws and if it makes sense. Pure magical questions are hard to answer because they are usually so open ended and really depend on your opinion.

Comment: @Shadowzee I have edited to share an idea I have just thought. I am divided by the idea in EDIT2 or the solution which you proposed in the answer.

Comment: This question looks like it's going to be pretty opinion based.  As a test, you can apply the "not any answer" test to your question.  Can you identify an answer which *isn't* an answer to your question as written?  If that's hard to do, then the question is probably opinion based.  As is, the only requirement I see is "different from white."  "draw on vital matter" or "draw on unimportant energy" are two example answer which fit your description, but probably are not the answer you are looking for.  Questions for which any answer is acceptable are not good fits for WB.SE

Comment: Another test is to see whether, given two answers A and B, can we determine which one is better based on the text of the question?

Comment: @programmer23 Consuming someone elses Ki would make dark magic appear evil since your draining the life energy of someone else. If you want to use that system, you should ask how to address flaws in a separate question. Something similar could be the Light and Dark side of the Force from starwars and that could also be a good point of reference for determining how your dark magics work.

Comment: I like your question, but I'm afraid is primarily opinion-based: there's aren't any elements to tell why any answer would be better than any other, or to say it is a wrong answer. However, I think your idea of black magic draining other living creatures' energy is actually quite good. It makes room for moral questioning (dark magic is powerful but evil). If you want to limit its power you can say that, for example, in order to get the vital energy they must touch a living creature to drain its *ki*. The bigger the creature, the more energy, but also more energy in animals than plants.

Comment: Why are you using the word edit in your post? Do you want us to edit that section for you? This is likely why the question was closed. Also you did not answer my question. You did scientifically define vital energy. At this point I can only presume you mean calories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dark Magic consumes emotional energy. The stronger ones emotions, the stronger the black magic and overtime casters of black magic become dead inside and oblivious to the plight of others as their emotions are gradually reduced to nothing.

Comment: Interesting, so you mean something like the more it uses Dark Energy, the more Sorrow and emotional Pain has the user?

Comment: @programmer23 You could spin it either way. The way I picture it is it uses the emotions of the caster (or maybe another person). So it could be happiness or anger, sadness or excitement. However the more they use, the harder it becomes for them to feel the emotions.

Comment: I like your idea. If I don't find any idea which could be more suitable for the story, I would choose the solution you proposed.

Comment: +1 That's how it worked for Darth Vader. :)

Comment: I think I will do both, the Magic will need energy from outside, but the user will loose its sanity as well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### Make Dark magic drain Sanity

Instead of *losing* something, you *see* things that are not there. You *hear* things. Too much dark magic makes the crackling of lightning sounds like whispers of the dead, the energy balls will have a face and looks like it's laughing while being launched in the air.

In the peak of this sanity drain, you see Shadow figures that coax you to murder people without any reason. Or kill your friends or family and perceive them as enemies. Or if you cannot handle the fear and despair, you die of insanity.

Comment: The idea is good, but I prefer saving these entities you described in other plot elements (they will be related to Dark Magic though)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE! I see you've accepted a question. Next time you ask a question, you can include all of these kinds of exclusions in your question so that we can answer more precisely =))

Answer (score 2):

White magic drains vitality from the caster

Dark magic drains vitality from everyone and everything around the caster excluding the caster hence why it's really dark.

White magic will leave the caster drained and unconscious if overused but black magic will kill everything around the caster.

Edit after the OP edit

Dark magic drains from a set range. Once drained, you need to move where more life is leaving a lifeless barren area behind.

Comment: I like the idea! Is quite similar as I thought, but the range element is something more limited and makes harder to the wizard to use it

Answer (score 2):

Dark Magic as an outside destructive force which you describe could backleash at its caster: if you create a fire ball and throw it towards your enemies, you burn your hands, if you create a whole field of flames burning everyone inside you suffer severe burns on your own body as well. 
This is a limitation which would keep people from frequently casting powerful dark spells, as the price would be their life andlogously to white magic.

Comment: Your suggestion is good, but I think it wouldn't fit with the history, because I want to perform some magic battles, I need something more flexible.

Comment: Especially in battle scenarios this would balance light and dark magic, as dark mages performing massive damage would require white mages for supportive healing, giving both types of magic equal right and balance in your scenario - considereing that you have mages of both types in all of your factions.

Comment: In this case the "good" faction can only use White magic while the "evil" faction can use both magics

Answer (score 1):

I assume vital energy is the sugars our bodies need to survive so dark magic may use heat energy to ionise the molecules in the air creating the lightening and the energy balls.

Comment: My bad, I have not explained with enough detail what Vital Energy was. I hope now it is more clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It could inflict some psychological damage, taxing the magic user's sanity. Or perhaps to match the more tangible nature of the magic, it could be more tangible damage - premature aging, maybe

Comment: Losing user's sanity I would take it for Dark Magic, but Aging is more related to white one due to Ki leak.

Answer (score 1):

Dark magic could consume direct physical 'energy', taking parts of the body away to power the spell. This would cause Dark Magic to do direct damage to the body of the caster. Enhanced aging, opening wounds on yourself as bits are pulled away to power the spell. Extreme spells could leave parts of the caster shriveled and 'mummified' if they overcast.

Comment: I assimilate this effects more when using White Magic, because when the Ki is being consumed, the body is losing life energy and therefore producing some effects you described.